# No module named idnadata

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I tried to add the module idnadata to cx_Freeze; idnadata exists in idna folder:

```
C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\idna
```

I used the code below in setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
packages = ['idnadata']
include_files = ['C:\\Users\\seyed_vahid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\idna']
setup(name = "instagram",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "test",
    options = {'build_exe': {'packages':packages,
        'include_files':include_files}},
    executables = [Executable("instagram.py")],
)
```

I ran setup.py by :

```
python setup.py build
```

But I get the error below :

```
ImportError: No module named 'idnadata'
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Verify 
C:\Users\seyed_vahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\idna is in path.

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved the problem thanks to

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys


#main
exe = Executable(script="test.py", base="Win32GUI")
buildOptions = dict(excludes = ["tkinter"], includes =["idna.idnadata"], optimize=1)
setup(name = "instagram",version = "1.0", description = "test", executables = [exe], options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions))
```

Answer (score 0):

idna itself is already being added, but for some reasons, the idnadata module is being left out. include idna.idnadata to fix this

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys


#main
exe = Executable(script="instagram.py", icon="instagram.ico", base="Win32GUI")
buildOptions = dict(excludes = ["tkinter"], includes =["idna.idnadata"], optimize=1)
setup(name = "instagram",version = "1.0", description = "test", executables = [exe], options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions))
```